# How to bypass Geo blocking on SoundCloud?

Tags: orbot

Some music in my SoundCloud android app isn't availaible in my country. How do I get around this using Orbot? I tried switching on Apps VPN mode and selecting SoundCloud, (set location as US first, then UK) but that didn't work. My phone isn't rooted.

Comment: It's possible that the soundcloud app itself is snitching on you, or your account information is. In those cases, connecting different locations won't help.

Comment: That's what I thought, although I don't remember giving my location in account details. The location setting in my phone is off, too. But still, I went to their website through Orfox expecting this to be solved (no log in). Didn't work again. I could listen music somewhere else of course, but I'm curious why this isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

Because tor-exit-nodes are popular by many websites on the web, (as mentioned before) they are blacklisted.

This happened because there are so little volunteers to become the exit nodes that it is a miracle that someone can access the internet without getting blocked (and I mean clear web / clearnet).

A possible solution to your problem with location would be to get a good VPN service with many servers and locations so that you can access SoundCloud without getting blocked by it.

Good luck!!

Comment: Furthermore, it is suggested by the tor project that you use a VPN every time you connect to the internet through tor.

Comment: And in your occasion you could try VPNs with mobile versions

Comment: *"Furthermore, it is suggested by the tor project that you use a VPN every time you connect to the internet through tor."* **--** i very much doubt that! please show us some evidence for this claim. i just have a link which rather suggests the opposite: https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq#IsTorLikeAVPN

Answer (score 0):

Tor exit nodes are often detected by web services, so if you insist on using Tor for this, you'll have to try (New Identity button at top right corner) lots of exit nodes until you find one not in their lists.